# Can I get Atom Script plugin to run in WSL Bash, not cmd?

Tags: windows, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to write python code and run it in Atom editor using the Script plugin. I've previously been using the ubuntu terminal for windows 10, but it seems like Script is running in cmd.exe, which results in error (because i haven't set up python or my packages there)

When running in my ubuntu terminal everything works fine.
Is there any way to get Script to use the ubuntu terminal instead of cmd?

EDIT: Title edited from "Can I get atom Script plugin to run in another terminal, not cmd?" after Eryk's comment.

Comment: WSL bash uses the same console as CMD. These are both shells, not terminals or consoles. The console is a system resource that's hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. It seems you're looking for a way to get this script plugin to run WSL bash.exe instead of cmd.exe, so you'll be able to access the Python packages you've configured in WSL.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you for clearing that up.